# Why were Stormcrows renamed to Second Sons in Game of Thrones tv show?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In books there are several sellswords companies, among them two fighting for Daenerys: Second Sons and Stormcrows. Daario Naharis is one of three co-captains of Stormcrows, Second Sons are under command of Mero. In the TV show however, there is one company, Second Sons, under Daario Naharis command. Why was this change made? If the main goal was to simplify things a bit, why didn't scenario writers just remove Second Sons from the show? Why merge them, by keeping Stormcrows plotline (Daario Naharis killing the other two co-captains etc.) and Second Sons name?

Comment: Second Sons has a lot more dramatic effect and connection to the rest of the show. Oberyn arriving at Dorne is like "Joffrey is insulted. I am, after all, only the second son." and Tyrion responds "Speaking as a fellow Second Son.". Inheritance, rights of claim, brotherhood, are a big there. Stormcrow is like ..... generic cool name #1456.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name change may be due to the similarity with the [Stone Crows](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stone_Crows), a hill tribe that Tyrion encounters in Season One.

This would be consistent with other name changes by the show, such as [changing Asha Greyjoy to Yara Greyjoy](http://winteriscoming.net/2011/07/27/producers-confirm-asha-name-change/) to make the name less similar to Osha the Wildling:

> David also confirmed reports that producers are working on changing the name of Theon Greyjoy’s sister, who in the books is called Asha. “We’re a little bit worried about the Osha/Asha sounding too close together,” David said, making a reference to the Season 1 wildling character. “So it might be a slightly different name."

Comment: Arguably that raises the question of why the Stone Crows couldn't have been renamed instead.

Comment: Great idea, retcon something that happened millions of years ago... they might not have known if they were going to use the second sons in the show while they were filming saeson 1.

Comment: @kuhl do you have any reference for the claim that Asha was renamed Yara to avoid confusion with Osha the Wildling?

Comment: @Aegon [It is known.](https://www.accesshollywood.com/articles/game-of-thrones-begins-filming-season-2-will-break-for-emmys-104401/)

Comment: @Mooz Thanks mate!

Comment: @Aegon it's also referenced in the link provided in the answer. Thought about including a quote, since the change is an example to support my answer rather then the answer I didn't know if it made sense to include a quote for asha or if it would just confuse things.

Comment: @kuhl didn't notice it, sorry about that. To make it clear, it was not critique, I was only asking for reference for that. I did [upvote the answer before asking the question](http://imgur.com/ajGbD32) ;)

Comment: @DariM my guess would be that the Stone Crows were introduced first, which would also fit for Asha/Yara. If so it's bad planning, they should have kept the more prominent group or person's name the same and planned ahead to change the names of the other one.

Comment: @Aegon understood. And I have debated back and forth and adding a quote (didn't know if it would muddle things, especially when I can't find a quote for the Storm Crows change), if you didn't notice the link others may not have either and so a quote may be needed.

Comment: Just in case, the quote is at the bottom of the link shared by Mooz

Comment: @DariM - maybe because they looked a bit like the band The Black Crows.